# ¿Se pueden crear estructuras dinamicas en lenguaje ensamblador(nasm x64)?

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, ensamblador, programación-bajo-nivel, nasm

Necesito implementar un árbol binario en lenguaje ensamblador mi idea era encontrar una forma de reservar memoria dinámicamente crear un struc nodo y un struct árbol.
Pensé en usar algún tipo de struct como en c, pero lo que encontré simplemente funciona para reservar memoria usando una macro con lo cual no sirve, intente crearla usando la pila reservando memoria para el valor y  4 bytes para almacenar la dir. de las demás variables, funciona pero no puedo usar la pila ya que la necesito para otros propósitos y el uso de la misma se vuelve muy complejo y no es nada eficiente:
mi pregunta es hay alguna manera de reservar memoria dinámica en ensamblador, ya sea usando algún segmento especial no conocido por mi persona, o simplemente no la hay, y de no existir, alguna idea de como emularlo sin usar el segmento de pila.